# Does loopback 3 supports where filter with skip + limit?

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I am working on Loopback with version 3, 
Does It supports where filter with skip and Limit, I am trying to apply for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, I have always used "offset" but in docs there is an option for skip also. Please checkout at [skip in loopback3](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Skip-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply skip and limit with pagination. This code is help full for you.

**example is now :**

```
Users.getList = function (filter, cb) {
  Users.find({
    where: {
      condition
    },
    limit: filter.limit,
    skip: filter.skip
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip and limit in the loopback where condition. I assume that you are trying to get the answer for something like the query **SELECT * FROM schemaName.tableName limit 10,5** using loopback, for that you can use the following peace of code

```
modelName.find({
   order: 'id DESC',
   skip: 10,
   limit: 5,
 });
```